# Writing text with a for cycle

Tags: c#, for-loop, text

```
for (int i = 0; i<count; i++)
{
  if (Herojai[i].Jėga == Herojai[i].Intelektas || Herojai[i].Jėga == Herojai[i].Vikrumas || Herojai[i].Intelektas == Herojai[i].Vikrumas)
  {
  string text = Herojai[i].Vardas; // (the thing I want to write)
  File.WriteAllText(@"xxx.csv", text);
  }
}
```

With this code, every loop where the if gets passed, the text gets overwritten for new one. I don't know how to write a new line in the CSV every loop.

Comment: Look in the documentation about what methods the `File` class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netframework-4.7.2) offers (hint: it is something with "Append" in its method name). But much better would be to open the file once (File.CreateText, see doc link again fo explanation and code example) and continually write those lines.

Comment: `File.WriteAllText` is never the best choice when processing line by line.

Comment: Can you use a stream for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, I would use `StringBuilder` class to connected string values in `If` condition, then let all content write to a file.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    if (Herojai[i].Jėga == Herojai[i].Intelektas || Herojai[i].Jėga == Herojai[i].Vikrumas || Herojai[i].Intelektas == Herojai[i].Vikrumas)
    {

        sb.Append(Herojai[i].Vardas);
    }
}

File.WriteAllText(@"xxx.csv", sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var items = Herojai.Where(i => i.Jėga == i.Intelektas || i.Jėga == i.Vikrumas || i.Intelektas == i.Vikrumas)
                   .Select(i => i.Vardas);
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"xxx.csv"))
{
    foreaach(var item in items)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use AppendAllText method:

```
File.AppendAllText(@"xxx.csv", text + Environment.NewLine);
```

Instead of:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"xxx.csv", text);
```

Answer (score -2):

File.WriteAllText will open a file, write the text, and then close it.  It will overwrite whatever is already in the file.

Comment: That does not answer the question.

Comment: Yeah, that is just repeating what is already in the question. ("_[...] the text gets overwritten for new one [...]_").

Comment: ... Just exactly as I said and I don't know how to change it.